Use AWS KMS key to decrypt file in another account
I have an account A that has KMS key used to encrypt files in account B. How can I use this key to decrypt files in s3 bucket inside account B? When I assume role from account A I lose ability to access S3 bucket inside account B.
Can you provide any documentation related to this situation?

Check this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/key-policy-modifying-external-accounts.html
